# Using @2x~ipad on iPhone 6+

Tags: ipad, iphone-6-plus

I have an app that use huge images to fit the iPad @2x~ipad. I would like to use those same images in the iPhone version of my universal app. Is there a way I can use those same images for iPhone 6+ @3x ?

I don't want to have a very similar image for both, the app will get large in the MB department.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to not use the automatic naming standards and write code that decides which image name to use based on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using your large image in a button. The code you are currently using probably looks something like this.

[buttonView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:largeImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Do this instead.

```
 NSString *pictFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"largeImage" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *imageToDisplay = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pictFile];
    UIImage *checkboxImage  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageToDisplay.CGImage scale:  [UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:imageToDisplay.imageOrientation];

[buttonView setImage:checkboxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I have lots of large images and I started doing this when the retina displays came out. It works just as well for new phones. You can run into problems if the frame is too large for the image. e.g. the @3x frame size is 100x100 but your image is only 90x90. If that happens, force the image scale @2x. You wont’t be able to see a difference for photos. I can see a difference for my large drawings on the iPhone 6 Plus—so I’m leaving the scale factor at 2 for them.

I am in the process of getting rid of all of my @1x and @2x images and using just @3x images that are named without an @. Works in the simulator for buttons and backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another example of using one very large image instead of three. This time I put a large background image into the entire view rather than a button. The key part of this code is, self.BGView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; which resizes the image so that it fits into the view.

```
- (void)pickBackgroundImage {

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGPoint midPoint = [Utilities findMidpoint:self.view];

    NSString *pictFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Background" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *imageToDisplay = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pictFile];
    imageToDisplay  = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageToDisplay.CGImage scale:scale orientation:imageToDisplay.imageOrientation];

    CGRect pictFrame;
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        CGFloat imageWidth = (unsigned int)(.9f * self.view.frame.size.width);
        pictFrame = CGRectMake(midPoint.x - imageWidth/2, midPoint.y - imageWidth/2, imageWidth, imageWidth);
        pictFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.origin.y + .3f * pictFrame.origin.y;
    } else {
        CGFloat imageWidth = (unsigned int)(self.view.frame.size.height - 20 - 44);
        pictFrame = CGRectMake(midPoint.x - imageWidth/2, midPoint.y - imageWidth/2, imageWidth, imageWidth);
        pictFrame.origin.y = 10;
    }
    self.BGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToDisplay];
    self.BGView.frame = pictFrame;
    self.BGView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self.view insertSubview:self.BGView atIndex:0];
}
```